# Nested loops, moving backwards in an intro to C++ assignment

Tags: c++, loops, nested-loops

***UPDATE**: Thank you all who tried to help. I appreciate your time. As you'll see by the comment I marked as an answer and my response to it, it seems our lectures fell behind a couple of weeks... or maybe I moved too quickly through previous labs and started this one too early. Either way, I was given a solution and I understand why it works, which I find much more valuable than copying and pasting just to get the assignment completed.*

***UPDATE 2***: My professor gave me a hint towards the solution of doing it with only loops and no arrays. Here's the new one that I figured out with his hint:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < min(i, 12 - i); j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < pow(2.0, j); k++)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
 }
```

Output:

```
*
***
*******
***************
*******************************
***************************************************************
*******************************
***************
*******
***
*
```

---

***Original Post:***

I've got the first part, now I just need to print these asterisks in reverse so that it forms a sideways triangle. I've been at this for days and I can't figure it out. We can only use the asterisk **once** in the program. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pow(2.0, i); j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
*
**
****
********
****************
********************************
****************************************************************
```

The closest I've come to solving this is displaying another row of stars under it, but they were all the same length. Sometimes I create an infinite loop of a wall of asterisks, sometimes I display a seemingly random amount of asterisks in dozens of rows. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: Sideways triangle sort of shape. The row under the longest output of asterisks should be the same length as the one above it, then the net would be as long as the one above the second longest and so on. 


I tried using the sqrt function (k > sqrt(i)), thinking it would reverse (j < pow(2.0, i)), and I also tried (k > sqrt(j)), but neither worked.

Comment: const char asteriskUsedOnlyOnce = '*';

Comment: So, basically, you want i to increase to 7 and then decrease to 0?

Comment: Are you allowed to define subroutines? Use containers from the standard library? Use `std::string`?

Comment: Recursivity would be a nice way to increase and decrease

Comment: I can just add the string library, but we can't call the asterisk or use it at all more than once. We can't say use for example: string asterisk = "*"; and then call asterisk twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pow(2.0, a[i]); j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Or this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for (int i = -6; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pow(2.0, 6 - (i < 0 ? -i : i)); j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. We were assigned this homework three weeks ago, but we just learned arrays yesterday. I understand why your top solution works, so I can use that. I can see how "i" is indexed in the "j" for loop.          I usually don't like just copying code, because I want to learn, but I've been at this for such a long time because he didn't teach us arrays until yesterday and it just hasn't clicked yet.  But, if you're still paying attention, why didn't you specify the size of the array for "a"? Shouldn't there be a numerical value in there?

Comment: If you initialize array at the definition by using `{...}` you need not specify array size if you want the size be equal to number of elements. In this case `{0, 1, ... 0}` contains 13 elements so the compiler knows that you meant `int a[13]`. This is convenient if later you decide to add more elements - new size will be calculated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Store them as strings (char *), push these strings onto a stack and print the stack by popping one by one. Voila!

Comment: The instructor said we should only be using nested loops, and can only use the asterisk character or call the asterisk string once. There should be one or two more for loops in there I think.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I will only give you half the answer. Hopefully you can figure out the rest.

```
for (int i = -6; i < 7; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with `for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)`

and then use a function `f(x)` that maps

```
 0->0
 1->1
...
 5->5
 6->6
 7->5
 8->4
...
12->0
```

so that you use the nested loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < f(i); j++)
```